# correlation tests

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, inference

I want to study the correlation between the individual's level of education (1=high school or less, 2=associate degree) and the customer service received in a convenience store (1=good, 2=bad), should I use spearman or phi test?

Answer (score 0):

Because both of your variables are categorical and have two levels, it won't matter if you treat them as nominal variables or ordinal variables.

Therefore, for a measure of association, you could use either *phi* or a traditional measure of association for ordinal variables (Kendall or Spearman). In this case, it won't matter if you use either Spearman or Kendall correlation.

Any of these measures can also be paired with a test of significance, or you could generate confidence intervals for any of them.

```
Matrix = matrix(c(10, 14, 15, 9), ncol=2,
                dimnames = list(Education = c("HighSchool", "Associates"),
                                Service   = c("Good", "Bad")))

Matrix

   ###             Service
   ### Education    Good Bad
   ### HighSchool   10  15
   ### Associates   14   9

library(rcompanion)

phi(Matrix, digits=4)

   ### -0.2085

library(DescTools)

SpearmanRho(Matrix)

   ### -0.2085

KendallTauB(Matrix)

   ### -0.2085
```